# Distort XML format

Tags: jquery, xml

I am using jQuery object to append elements and modify the values of an XML document, which I am initializing using a XML string which has nodes such as `<tgroup>`, `<table>`, `<row>`, `<tbody>`, etc. as seen below.

```
var str = "<txml> <table><tsnipp><tbody> <row> ... </row>  </tbody> </tsnipp> </table> </txml>"
```

Now I am creating a jQuery object using `$(str)`. The `<tsnipp>` element in the XML document is under the `<table>` element; however, when inspecting the jQuery object using Firebug, I see it as above the `<table>` element, and thus the `<tsnipp>` is at the same level as the `<table>`, as opposed to being one of its children. I think jQuery itself organizes it that way because it thinks the `<table>` element is an HTML element.

By just changing `<table>` to `<d_table>`, jQuery does the right thing.

I wanted to use jQuery to manipulate the object as it is easier to manipulate as a DOM object. However, converting it into a string and then to a jQuery object will require a lot of regular expressions to replace certain strings into others, back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML) to parse the document as XML instead of HTML:

```
var doc = $($.parseXML(str));
```

Comment: Yes it works.. If someone is looking for how to parse use this code: var serl = new XMLSerializer(doc)
var txt = serl.serializeToString(doc);